# Induction on predicates with product type arguments

Tags: coq, induction, coq-tactic

If I have a predicate like this:

```
Inductive foo : nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | Foo : forall n, foo n n.
```

then I can trivially use induction to prove some dummy lemmas:

```
Lemma foo_refl : forall n n',
  foo n n' -> n = n'.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

However, for a predicate with product type arguments:

```
Inductive bar : (nat * nat) -> (nat * nat) -> Prop :=
  | Bar : forall n m, bar (n, m) (n, m).
```

a similar proof for nearly identical lemma gets stuck because all assumptions about variables disappear:

```
Lemma bar_refl : forall n n' m m',
  bar (n, m) (n', m') -> n = n'.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction H.
  (* :( *)
```

Why is this happening? If I replace `induction` with `inversion`, then it behaves as expected.

The lemma is still provable with `induction` but requires some workarounds:

```
Lemma bar_refl : forall n n' m m',
  bar (n, m) (n', m') -> n = n'.
Proof.
  intros.
  remember (n, m) as nm.
  remember (n', m') as n'm'.
  induction H.
  inversion Heqnm. inversion Heqn'm'. repeat subst.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Unfortunately, this way proofs gets completely cluttered and are impossible to follow for more complicated predicates.

One obvious solution would be to declare `bar` like this:

```
Inductive bar' : nat -> nat -> nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | Bar' : forall n m, bar' n m n m.
```

This solves all the problems. Yet, for my purposes, I find the previous ("tupled") approach somewhat more elegant. Is there a way to keep the predicate as it is and still be able to do manageable inductive proofs? Where does the problem even come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that induction can only works with variables, not constructed terms. This is why you should first prove something like

```
Lemma bar_refl : forall p q, bar p q -> fst p = fst q.
```

which is trivially proved by `now induction 1.` to prove your lemma.

If you don't want the intermediate lemma to have a name, your solution is the correct one: you need to help Coq with `remember` to generalize your goal, and then you'll be able to prove it.

I don't remember exactly where this restriction comes from, but I recall something about making some unification problem undecidable.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like sticking to the curried version of a predicate is my best option then...

Comment: Don't forget to check the correct answer to help future visitors

Answer (score 1):

Often in these situation one can do induction on one of the sub-terms.

In your case your lemma can be proved by induction on `n`, with

```
Lemma bar_refl : forall n n' m m',  bar (n, m) (n', m') -> n = n'.
Proof. induction n; intros; inversion H; auto. Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... all assumptions about variables disappear... Why is this happening? If I replace `induction` with `inversion`, then it behaves as expected.

The reason that happens is described perfectly in this blog post:
[Dependent Case Analysis in Coq without Axioms](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrw12/dep-destruct.html)
by James Wilcox. Let me quote the most relevant part for this case:

> When Coq performs a case analysis, it first abstracts over all indices. You may have seen this manifest as a loss of information when using `destruct` on predicates (try destructing `even 3` for example: it just deletes the hypothesis!), or when doing induction on a predicate with concrete indices (try proving `forall n, even (2*n+1) -> False` by induction on the hypothesis (not the `nat`) -- you'll be stuck!). Coq essentially forgets the concrete values of the indices. When trying to induct on such a hypothesis, one solution is to replace each concrete index with a new variable together with a constraint that forces the variable to be equal to the correct concrete value. `destruct` does something similar: when given a term of some inductive type with concrete index values, it first replaces the concrete values with new variables. It doesn't add the equality constraints (but `inversion` does). The error here is about abstracting out the indices. You can't just go replacing concrete values with arbitrary variables and hope that things still type check. It's just a heuristic.

To give a concrete example, when using `destruct H.` one basically does pattern-matching like so:

```
Lemma bar_refl : forall n n' m m',
  bar (n, m) (n', m') -> n = n'.
Proof.
  intros n n' m m' H.
  refine (match H with
          | Bar a b => _
          end).
```

with the following proof state:

```
n, n', m, m' : nat
H : bar (n, m) (n', m')
a, b : nat
============================
n = n'
```

To get almost the exact proof state we should've erased `H` from the context, using the `clear H.` command: `refine (...); clear H.`. This rather primitive pattern-matching doesn't allow us to prove our goal.
Coq abstracted away `(n, m)` and `(n',m')` replacing them with some pairs `p` and `p'`, such that `p = (a, b)` and `p' = (a, b)`. Unfortunately, our goal has the form `n = n'` and there is neither `(n,m)` nor `(n',m')` in it -- that's why Coq didn't change the goal with `a = a`.

But there is a way to tell Coq to do that. I don't know how to do *exactly* that using tactics, so I'll show a proof term. It's is going to look somewhat similar to @Vinz's solution, but notice that I didn't change the statement of the lemma:

```
  Undo.  (* to undo the previous pattern-matching *)
  refine (match H in (bar p p') return fst p = fst p' with
          | Bar a b => _
          end).
```

This time we added more annotations for Coq to understand the connections between the components of `H`'s type and the goal -- we explicitly named the `p` and `p'` pairs and because we told Coq to treat our goal as `fst p = fst p'` it will replace `p` and `p'` in the goal with `(a,b)`. Our proof state looks like this now:

```
n, n', m, m' : nat
H : bar (n, m) (n', m')
a, b : nat
============================
fst (a, b) = fst (a, b)
```

and simple `reflexivity` is able to finish the proof.

I think now it should be clear why `destruct` works fine in the following lemma (don't look at the answer below, try to figure it out first):

```
Lemma bar_refl_all : forall n n' m m',
  bar (n, m) (n', m') -> (n, m) = (n', m').
Proof.
  intros. destruct H. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer: because the goal contains the same pairs that are present in the hypothesis's type, so Coq replaces them all with appropriate variables and that will prevent the information loss.

Answer (score 0):

Another way ...

```
Lemma bar_refl n n' m m' : bar (n, m) (n', m') -> n = n'.
Proof.
  change (n = n') with (fst (n,m) = fst (n',m')).
  generalize (n,m) (n',m').
  intros ? ? [ ]; reflexivity.
Qed.
```